# PCR test at Tirana International Airport

Tags: albania, covid-19

My partner and I will be visiting Albania in a month. On the way back, we'll need to do PCR tests. I found information about the testing center at the airport. If someone used the services of this center, could you please tell me about your experience? How reliable their information is (that they are open 24 hours and that the results are returned in 90 minutes)? Is it the same on the weekends (our flight back is on Sunday morning)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.